# How can i start the Sonar Qube with java 8

Tags: java-8, sonarqube, devops

I have download the `SonarQube 8.7.1.` community version Software. I am getting below error while start sonar batch file in windows console.

[image]

> My main idea is to connect with `java 8` but this `sonarQube` version is asking `java 11`."

Any additional settings needed to do for run the `sonarqube` with `java 8` ?

Comment: The question might be better suited for [superuser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code or error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: **Why** do you think you need to run Sonarqube with Java 8? You know that this JVM version is entirely unrelated with the version of code you're about to analyze. Obviously Java 8 won't run this version of Sonarqube, so bite the bullet and install Java 11.

Comment: @JoachimSauer i am looking for the compatibility. presently i am using java 8 so i want to use sonar qube with java8

Comment: @tripleee Thanks for your good Advice. next time on words i will follow the instructions which you provided. Great advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java 8 support question has already been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22497165/does-sonarqube-support-java-8-yet) & Java 11 support question has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58948103/sonarqube-requires-java-11-to-run-for-java-1-8-0-221)

Either install JDK11 or downgrade to a lower version of SonarQube that came out before March 2014 would be my suggestion.